# Javascript dropdown immediatly closes itself when clicking on a value inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm converting a dropdown from JQuery to vanilla JS, and I'm having some issues when I click on the dropdown it opens and I can select a value inside of it, but when I click on said value the value will be selected and it will instantly close.

I managed to narrow the problem down to this line

```
   if($('*[data-toggle], *[data-totoggle]').is(e.target) || $('*[data-toggle], *[data-totoggle]').has(e.target).length){
        return false;
    }
```

In my vanilla js I replaced the above jquery code with this

```
    if (document.querySelector('*[data-toggle], *[data-totoggle]') === e.target) {
        return false;
    }
```

This does not seem to achive the same thing as the jquery `has` and `is` functions, are there any equivalent of those in vanilla JS ?

codesandbox example > https://codesandbox.io/s/little-frost-tzefn?file=/src/index.js

Vanilla js version :

```
    (function () {
    
    
        document.querySelectorAll('*[data-toggle]').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    
            e.preventDefault();
            const toToggle = element.dataset.toggle
    
            // Close all other toggle elements and toggle the one you clicked
            document.querySelectorAll('*[data-totoggle], *[data-toggle]').forEach(function (toggleElements) {
    
                if (toggleElements.dataset.toggle === toToggle || toggleElements.dataset.totoggle === toToggle) {
                    toggleElements.classList.toggle('active')
                } else if (!toggleElements.classList.contains('onlyClick')) {
                    toggleElements.classList.remove('active');
                }
            })
    
            // toggle text if needed
            if (element.dataset.toggletext) {
                const toggleText = element.dataset.toggletext.split(',')
    
                if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
                    element.html(toggleText[0])
                } else {
                    element.html(toggleText[1])
                }
            }
    
            // Remove toggle function from permanent elements
            if (element.classList.contains('permanent')) {
                element.querySelector('*[data-toggle="' + toToggle + '"]').removeAttribute('data-toggle');
                element.querySelector('*[data-totoggle="' + toToggle + '"]').removeAttribute('data-totoggle');
            }
        }))
    
        // close elements when clicking outside of them
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            if (document.querySelector('*[data-toggle], *[data-totoggle]') === e.target) {
                return false;
            }
    
            document.querySelectorAll('*[data-toggle], *[data-totoggle]').forEach(function (element) {
                if (!element.classList.contains('onlyClick')) {
                    element.classList.remove('active')
                }
            })
    
            if (document.querySelector('*[data-slidetoggle], *[data-toslidetoggle]') === e.target) {
                return false;
            }
    
            document.querySelectorAll('*[data-slidetoggle]').forEach(function (element) {
                if (!element.classList.contains('onlyClick')) {
                    element.classList.remove('active')
    
                    $('*[data-toslidetoggle]').slideUp();
                }
            })
        });
    
        // slide toggle elements
        document.querySelectorAll('*[data-slidetoggle]').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', function () {
            const slideToggle = this.dataset.slidetoggle
            this.classList.toggle('active');
            $('*[data-toslidetoggle="' + slideToggle + '"]').slideToggle(200);
    
            if (this.dataset.toggletext) {
                const toggleText = this.dataset.toggletext.split(',')
    
                if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
                    this.html(toggleText[0])
                } else {
                    this.html(toggleText[1])
                }
            }
        }))
        document.querySelector('*[data-trigger]').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            const toTrigger = e.target.dataset.trigger
            document.querySelector('.' + toTrigger).trigger('click');
        })
    })();
```

Comment: Code dumps like this are not that helpful, could you try and narrow down to a simple example demonstrating the problem, ideally create a working snippet here showing the problem.

Comment: Hey, I narrowed down my problem and edited my question.

Comment: That's better, but it's still a bit tricky to see what's happening.  If you click the `<>` icon inside the question editor, it allows you to create a working snippet a bit like jsBin etc, jQuery is even a quick select.  If you can show the jQuery one as a working snippet, then we can use this as a basis to create a pure JS version.  One thing I will say though, jquery works with collections, eg.. `$('div')` would return all div's, `querySelector` only ever returns a single element, so you might be after `querySelectorAll` instead.

Comment: Alright, managed to get a working codesandbox example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in your sandbox example. The dropdown only closes if i click on "All themes" again or outside the dropdown box.

Comment: Hey yea the jquery example works fine, the dropdown is supposed to close when clicked outside of the dropdown box. this does not work with the javascript code I tried,  I will add the vanilla javascript code to the question.